# Too many possible configurations in z3 using scala^z3

Tags: scala, logic, z3, smt

This is mainly a logic problem I guess...

I use this smtlib formula:

```
(declare-fun a () Bool)
(declare-fun b () Bool)
(declare-fun c () Bool)
(declare-fun d () Bool)
(assert (xor (and a (xor b c)) d))
```

Which is a term of this structure(in my opinion, at least):

```
    XOR
    | |
  AND d
  | |
  a XOR
    | |
    b c
```

My guess: The resultSet would look like this:

```
{ab, ac, d}
```

But its this using scala^z3 ctx.checkAndGetAllModels():

```
{ab, d, ac, ad, abcd}
```

Why is ad and abcd in there?
Is it possible to get only the results I would expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Scala (without Z3) to show that there are, in fact, more solutions to the constraint:

```
val tf = Seq(true, false)
val allValid =
  for(a <- tf; b <- tf; c <- tf; d <- tf; 
      if((a && (b ^ c)) ^ d)) yield (
    (if(a) "a" else "") + (if(b) "b" else "") +
    (if(c) "c" else "") + (if(d) "d" else ""))

allValid.mkString("{ ", ", ", " }")
```

Prints:

```
{ abcd, ab, ac, ad, bcd, bd, cd, d }
```

So unless I'm missing something, the question is, why does it *not* find *all* solutions? Now here is the answer to that one. (Spoiler alert: "getAllModels" doesn't really get all models.) First, let's reproduce what you observed:

```
import z3.scala._
val ctx = new Z3Context("MODEL" -> true)
val a = ctx.mkFreshConst("a", ctx.mkBoolSort)
val b = ctx.mkFreshConst("b", ctx.mkBoolSort)
val c = ctx.mkFreshConst("c", ctx.mkBoolSort)
val d = ctx.mkFreshConst("d", ctx.mkBoolSort)
val cstr0 = ctx.mkXor(b, c)
val cstr1 = ctx.mkAnd(a, cstr0)
val cstr2 = ctx.mkXor(cstr1, d)
ctx.assertCnstr(cstr2)
```

Now, if I run: `ctx.checkAndGetAllModels.foreach(println(_))`, I get:

```
d!3 -> false
a!0 -> true
c!2 -> false
b!1 -> true

d!3 -> true    // this model is problematic
a!0 -> false

d!3 -> false
a!0 -> true
c!2 -> true
b!1 -> false

d!3 -> true
a!0 -> true
c!2 -> false
b!1 -> false

d!3 -> true
a!0 -> true
c!2 -> true
b!1 -> true
```

Now, the problem is that the second model is an *incomplete* model. Z3 can return it, because whatever the values for `b` and `c` are, the constraint is satisfied (`b` and `c` are *don't-care* variables). The current implementation of `checkAndGetAllModels` simply negates the model to prevent repetition; in this case, it will ask for another model such that `(not (and d (not a)))` holds. This will prevent all other models with this two values from being returned. In a sense, the incomplete model actually represents four valid, completed, models.

By the way, what happens if you use the DSL of ScalaZ3 with the `findAll` function is that all models will be *completed* with default values when they are incomplete (and before they are used to compute the next one). In the context of the DSL we can do this, because we know the set of variables that appear in the formula. In this case, it's harder to guess how the model should be completed. One option would be for ScalaZ3 to remember which variables were used. A better solution would be for Z3 to have an option to always return values for don't-care variables, or perhaps simply to list all *don't-care* variables in a model.

Comment: Of course Owen and you are right. The results shown here are correct. In the end my problem is a different one. If you see my term as a configuration and everything that is true would be delivered, then it would be too much ;) I wanted a configuration where: If you choose a left-hand-side (in XOR), the complete right-hand-side should be false. Can this be accomplished?

Comment: One way would be to enhance the information in the model this way: "a->!d" "d->!a" "d->!b" "d->!c" etc... But in large models this is a lot of work...

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what "the complete right-hand-side" refers to. Considering your boolean expression as a tree, does that mean that you want all the _leafs_ of the right-hand-side to be false? Or as many of them as possible?

Comment: Consider the and/or tree to be a model. I would want a path from root to a leaf to be true and the rest false (and as many possible complete paths as there are). This would yield the results I mentioned in my question. Sorry about my question; seems like it went in the wrong direction. With those implications it is possible to create the result that I want to see. I hoped it could be easier than that ;)